# Programs that analyze word frequency?

Tags: editing, software, tools, text-analysis

I would like a utility that could analyze a document and give me stats like this:

```
WORD:           FREQUENCY:
a               47,268
the             37,201
gross           215
irregardlessly  1
```

Does anyone know if this is available?

BTW, I'd rather not use an online tool. Call me paranoid, but uploading my unpublished novel to the internet, to me, would be akin to walking down main street with nothing but a condom on. :)

Comment: I don't understand your metaphor. Plus, I would say that this question should be asked on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @Ooker The word "akin" makes it a simile, right? :)

Comment: I know that you are making a simile, but I still don't see how not using an online tool is akin to walking down naked with only a condom on :-s

Comment: @Ooker I'm saying that I would feel exposed, naked. That I'm taking this personal, private, precious thing of mine and allowing it to be seen by the world, potentially. It could be stolen, plagiarized, even distributed as a whole in electronic form before I have a chance to get it published in print, rendering any print version less valuable. Again, you may call me paranoid if you like.

Comment: ok, you are halfly paranoid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My beloved [Scrivener](http://literatureandlatte.com/) does the job beautifully. Paste your text in and then go under Project —> Text Statistics and it gives you the list you're looking for.

Other people on this board have recommended [Word Counter](http://www.supermagnus.com/mac/Word_Counter/download.html) (Mac) and both [Primitive Word Counter](http://www.primitivezone.com/primitive-word-counter.html) and [yWriter](http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter5.html) (Windows), but I cannot speak to their utility as I've never used them.

Comment: I've started the trial, and while impressed with the program as a whole, the text statistics report is a bit weak. It produces a small box showing word, count and percentage of that word in the entire document. The report box is not resizable, meaning anything other than small words are cut off:  "produce," "producer," and "productivity" all register as separate words that only occur once, but they all only show up as "produ..." until the word is hovered over for a second, then a popup shows the word. I don't see how the report can be exported, either, which would be nice.

Comment: Caveat! There is an app in the Mac AppStore called _Word-Counter_, not _Word Counter_. (Note the dash). Don't buy it. It's not the same one that is referred to in the link in this answer and does *not* do word frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Notetab Light (and the paid version, too) for Windows offered this feature the last time I used it. It's an older text editor with loads features that I used before converting to Linux, which happened in 2007 or so.

I use an editor I made myself, now, with that feature and lots of others I like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Linux or Cygwin on Windows, you can get it to tell you just about anything you want to know about your text with a few lines of shell code. [Here's](http://doofussoftware.blogspot.com/2012/07/a-linux-one-liner-to-count-unique-words.html) one approach.

[Here's](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/work-shell-counting-words-and-letters) another article which explains the process in more detail.

In this case, you would probably first have to copy your text from its native format and then paste it without formatting into a text file so the internal formatting codes, etc. don't interfere with the logic.

The advantage of an approach like this is that, with a little effort, you can get your tool to report anything you want in exactly the format you want it in.

Microsoft is also talking about adding such shell capabilities into an upcoming release of Windows 10.

If you're on a Mac, you probably already have all of the necessary tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

Most Tex and LaTeX editors how text analysis that give you a number of uses of each word in a block, in a table, and so on.
For example TEXstudio is a popular one.